# Type Script - React Native: " ViewStyle " type issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

When I pass the parameter:

```
defaultButtonTextDark: {
     fontWeight: 'bold',
     color: 'white',
     fontSize: 16,
   },
```

into `ThemeManager` function :

```
const ThemeManager = (darkStyle: ViewStyle, lightStyle: ViewStyle) => {
  DO SOMETHING...
}
```

So it shows me the following error:

Type '{ fontWeight: "bold"; color: string; fontSize: number; }' has no properties in common with type 'ViewStyle'.ts(2559).

way of use the function:

```
<Text style={ThemeManager(styles.defaultButtonTextDark, styles.defaultButtonText)}>return default</Text>
```

What is the way to solve this type issue ?

Comment: How are you connecting defaultButtonTextDark and ViewStyle? Shouldn't you apply it as `darkStyle: ViewStyle.defaultButtonTextDark`? Will be hard to get to a conclusion without seeing more of your code.

Comment: i add example of use the funciton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ViewStyle type](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props) has no properties named `color`, `fontWeight` or `fontSize`.

It seems to me that you have a function named `ThemeManager` that returns a style meant for a `Text` component.

The type for the style prop of a react-native `Text` is defined in [TextStyle](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props).

Thus, the correct typing is as follows:

```js
const ThemeManager = (darkStyle: TextStyle, lightStyle: TextStyle) => {
  DO SOMETHING...
}
```

However, depending on how you have defined the type for `defaultButtonTextDark`, you might get troubles when it comes to the typing of `fontWeight` which has the following type:

```js
'normal' | 'bold' | '100' | '200' | '300' | '400' | '500' | '600' | '700' | '800' | '900'
```

To fix this, we could provide the type explicitly here.

```js
const defaultButtonTextDark: TextStyle = {
     fontWeight: 'bold',
     color: 'white',
     fontSize: 16,
}
```

On the other hand, if `defaultButtonTextDark` is defined in a StyleSheet, then you do not have these problems:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  defaultButtonTextDark: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});
```